# Unnest Arrays in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using a database that was created in a SMO DW in Azure from a PostgreSQL database. There are column in some of the tables that are arrays. I would like to unnest these columns to be able to use them but can not seem to find a way to do this. Any help would be ideal?

[image: User Column]

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those almost look like JSON arrays with [uniqueidentifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/uniqueidentifier-transact-sql)

So if you switch the curly brackets `{}` to square brackets `[]`, then you can unnest them with `OPENJSON`.

> ```
> create table Your_Table (
>  users varchar(100)
> );
>
> insert into Your_Table (users) values
> ('{"3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301"}'), 
> ('{"6F9619FF-8B86-D011-B42D-00C04FC964FF","0E984725-C51C-4BF4-9960-E1C80E27ABA0"}')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT TRY_CONVERT(uniqueidentifier, j.value) as user_guid
> FROM Your_Table
> CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(TRANSLATE(users,'{}','[]')) j
> ```

> | user_guid |
> | --- |
> | 3f2504e0-4f89-11d3-9a0c-0305e82c3301 |
> | 6f9619ff-8b86-d011-b42d-00c04fc964ff |
> | 0e984725-c51c-4bf4-9960-e1c80e27aba0 |

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cb7673ac2473722d38a6ee02a015c74d)*

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle it.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (userID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, users VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT INTO @tbl (users) VALUES
('{"01B334D2-64F9-4A3E-A5C3-D115E7A54A4E"}'),
('{"1BE8F1FC-08F1-4A73-A5FA-8A62AD0A1C47","504D4B75-27D8-42FF-9811-03B18247AE09"}'),
('{"AAD375D3-1244-4EC1-8346-DA783EBE591A"}');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT userID, users AS [Before]
    , QUOTENAME(TRIM('{}' FROM value), '{') AS [After]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(users, ',');
```

**Output**

```
+--------+------------------------------------------+
| userID |                  After                   |
+--------+------------------------------------------+
|      1 | {"01B334D2-64F9-4A3E-A5C3-D115E7A54A4E"} |
|      2 | {"1BE8F1FC-08F1-4A73-A5FA-8A62AD0A1C47"} |
|      2 | {"504D4B75-27D8-42FF-9811-03B18247AE09"} |
|      3 | {"AAD375D3-1244-4EC1-8346-DA783EBE591A"} |
+--------+------------------------------------------+
```